# add CHECK constraint to already populated table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, check-constraints

I created a table called `test` with column called `code`:

```
create table test(  
code char(3) not null);
```

I then populated the table with the following data:

```
insert into test values ('A12');
insert into test values ('B23');
insert into test values ('C45');
```

I then altered the column to make it char(4):

```
alter table test
alter column code char(4) not null;
```

I then added a 'X' to all existing data so that it becomes 4 characters long:

```
update test
  set code='X'+code
where LEN(code)=3;
```

So far so good but then when I tried to add a check constraint:

```
alter table test
add constraint codeCheck check (code like 'A-Z''A-Z''0-9''0-9');
```

I got this error:

`The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "codeCheck".`

I understand that the error implies that the existing data violates the check constraint that I am trying to add into the table, but why?

and how do I do it such that the existing data and check constraint do not violate each other?

Comment: Please use the { } button, not HTML markup, to format your post.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your pattern syntax is wrong. It should be

```
alter table test
add constraint codeCheck check (code like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your data doesn't match the like constraint.

Try

```
alter table test
     add constraint codeCheck check (code like '[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9]' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how it works with SQL Server but your like clause looks odd.
Try using

> '[A-Z]{2}\d{2}'